# Spring WebFlux: In controller under test, mocked service returned value not getting set as a JSON Response

Tags: spring-mvc, mockito, integration-testing, spring-webflux, spring-test-mvc

Having a problem with my mocked return response from my controller.

The async response is returning as the actual POJO not the serialized json.

Running the application and using Postman, the returned response is indeed a JSON Object... but testing it returns the actual mock POJO I've created...
here is my test case.

```
@WebMvcTest(CustomerController.class)
class CustomerControllerTest {
@Autowired
MockMvc mvc;

@MockBean
private CustomerService customerService;

private Mono<OtcBalanceResponse> responseMono;

private OtcBalanceResponse otcResponseMock;

@BeforeEach
void setupMocks() {
    OtcBalanceResponse otcResponseMock = new OtcBalanceResponse();
    otcResponseMock.setOtcBalance(new BigDecimal("1.30"));
    otcResponseMock.setUserId("testID");
    responseMono = Mono.just(otcResponseMock);
}
@Test
void testGetCustomerOTCBalance() throws Exception {

    when(customerService.getCustomerOTCBalance((OtcBalanceRequest) any()))
            .thenReturn(responseMono);

    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/customer/otc-balance").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    mvc.perform(requestBuilder).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.otcBalance").value(1.30));
}
```

}

here is my Controller class

```
  @GetMapping("/otc-balance")
  public Mono<OtcBalanceResponse> getCustomerOTCBalance(OtcBalanceRequest otcBalanceRequest){
    return customerService.getCustomerOTCBalance(otcBalanceRequest);
}
```

Here is my service

```
    public Mono<OtcBalanceResponse> getCustomerOTCBalance(OtcBalanceRequest request) {

    return webClientBuilder
            .baseUrl(customerBase)
            .build()
            .post()
            .uri(otcBalancePath)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(request))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(OtcBalanceResponse.class);
}
```

this is my logged result

```
Async:
Async started = true
 Async result = OtcBalanceResponse(otcBalance=1.30, otcRolloverFlag=false, isIncommMember=false, otcStartDate=null, otcEndDate=null)
```

Comment: As you are using async coding you should also do that with your test. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMvcRequestBuilders.html#asyncDispatch-org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult- on how to use `MockMvc` to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using webflux, the easiest path is to use webflux-specific classes:

- WebFluxTest instead of WebMvcTest
- WebTestClient instead of MockMvc

```java
@WebFluxTest(CustomerController.class)
class CustomerControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webClient;

    // ...

    @Test
    void testGetCustomerOTCBalance() throws Exception {

        when(customerService.getCustomerOTCBalance(any()))
                .thenReturn(responseMono);

        webClient.get().uri("/customer/otc-balance")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBody()
                .jsonPath("$.otcBalance").isEqualTo(1.30);

    }

}
```

Other remarks - you are not `OtcBalanceRequest` to the controller - but `any()` argument matcher accepts null. Using a `eq` argument matcher would make your test better - you would check that the request is correctly deserialized by the controller.

Comment: He isn't using full Spring Webflux so the `@WebFluxTest` won't work as that would require a reactive runtime as well. Nonetheless one should still be able to use the `WebTestClient` as that is only the client part and not the server part.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, this is good point. Upvoting your answer.

Comment: Actually I tried both answers, and they both work...

 @M.Deinum I believe that a reactive controller is working underneath the hood via annotation processing and because i have the correct dependencies supplied to my pom.xml
please see  https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-controller

Comment: I don't know which dependencies you have, however if you deploy to tomcat you won't have a reactive controller, just another way of writing async code. The fact that you use `@WebMvcTest` points/hints towards you aren't using full blown Webflux (with a reactive runtime like Netty) but rather use a reactive way of writing async controllers. Using Tomcat will only leverage the async part of reactive programming not backpressure etc. etc.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using Async coding (and not full webflux) you need to do that with `MockMvc` as well. The [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMvcRequestBuilders.html#asyncDispatch-org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult-) of the `MockMvcRequestBuilders` has an example of such a thing. Applying that to your code would make it something like this.

```java
@Test
void testGetCustomerOTCBalance() throws Exception {

    when(customerService.getCustomerOTCBalance((OtcBalanceRequest) any()))
            .thenReturn(responseMono);

    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/customer/otc-balance").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    MvcResult result = mvc.perform(requestBuilder).andExpect(request().asyncStarted())
        .andReturn();
    mvc.perform(asyncDispatch(result))
         .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.otcBalance").value(1.30));
}
```

Something along those lines.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've upvoted and marked it as the solution. 

However, just to be clear. As of Spring Starter 2.7.5 BOTH supplied answers in the comment section are working.

I believe due to supplying `<spring-boot-starter-webflux>` in my pom.xml, Annotation processing with `@Controller` uses the complete reactive webclient underneath the hood.

Comment: If you are using `spring-boot-starter-webflux` you should have been using `@WebFluxTest` in the first place and not `@WebMvcTest` as both setup a different infrastructure. You basically now use the old way (servlet) to test a reactive part (webflux). `@WebMvcTest` uses a special `DispatcherServlet` under the hood and only supports the async part of Reactive, where as `@WebFluxTest` will setup the full reactive infrastructure.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I switched the correct answer, as I was using the wrong test setup to begin with. I should have been using `@WebFluxTest` given that my project was utilizing `spring-boot-starter-webflux`

Comment: you should have made that clear in your question as the combination of an `@Controller` with only a `Mono` return type is supported, that combined with `@WebMvcTest` led to misleading conclusions :).